# Why is the output of this sanitize function unchanged?

Tags: coldfusion

I expect the following function to output a sanitized list of tags, but instead it outputs the original list unchanged. Dumping local.i on each iteration, however, shows the sanitized tag as one would expect:

```
<cfset this.tags = "tag!@%^-tag, anothersf-taggame, SDFSFtagged">

<cfset local.listPosition = 0>

<cfloop list="#this.tags#" index="local.i">
   <cfset local.i = ReReplace(local.i, "[^a-z0-9+##\-.]", "", "All")>
   <cfset local.listPosition = local.listPosition + 1>
   <cfset ListSetAt(this.tags, local.listPosition, local.i, ", ")>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
   #this.tags#
</cfoutput>
```

Any idea why this weird behavior is happening? It must be the [ListSetAt()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d83.html) function not appending the new value to the list, but why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

listSetAt() doesn't alter the list.  It returns a copy of the list with the alteration, so you need to do an assignment.

It looks like there's a lot of optimization available here, though.  Why are you looping over the list?  It looks like if you allow commas in the regex, you would get the same results as this loop.

Comment: I agree ben, I refactored it completely. I removed the regEx from the loop, got rid of the local.listPosition, and just set the list after the loop. The look is for validation, which I ommited from my example.